# How to obtain Facebook access token and Verify them on an HapiJS Server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement social authentication on a sample API I'm building. I want to be able to simply verify access tokens returned from facebook when a user tries to log in via Facebook.

I'm stuck at the moment as the docs isn't straightforward. I got to know about this URL for token verification but I haven't been able to find my way around it.

```
GET graph.facebook.com/debug_token?
    input_token={token-to-inspect}
    &access_token={app-token-or-admin-token}
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling

Comment: Hey @CBroe how do I generate an access token and input token. That's what I'm confused about.

Comment: different link then: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: To be honest, I find the docs not descriptive enough. I've read this over and all it does is tell me what the different tokens are and not how I can generate them.

Comment: "User access tokens are generally obtained via a login dialog and require a person to permit your app to obtain one."  The user will need to login to your app using, say, the Login Dialog using the JS SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web